# Linq: How to assign local variables within linq from array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that returns a simple `int[2]`. Both elements of the array need to each be assigned to an `int r` and `int c` local variables. I want to achieve this all within a single Linq query. Any way to do this?

This is pseudo code of what I want to achieve, but obviously it doesn't work. I don't know Linq very well and I'm trying to get better at it. `Method(r,c)` is the method that returns an `int[2]`. I want to pull each element out and assign `int[0] = r` and `int[1] = c`.

```cs
void Foo(int r, int c)
{
    Method(r,c).Select(([0],[1]) => { r = [0]; c = [1]; });
}
```

```cs
int[] Method(int r, int c)
{
    ///stuff///
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### logic:

1. Method return int array with r and c
2. create `static class` to make a `Select` method
3. Select method input the int array and call `Func<int[],T>` and retrun T (T is Generic)

**[Online Test Demo Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cLoRxb)**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Method(1, 2).Select( (r,c) => new { r,c });
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    static int[] Method(int r,int c) => new[] {r,c};
}

public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static T Select<T>(this int[] ints, Func<int,int, T> func) => func(ints[0],ints[1]);
}
```

[image]

or you can use Method with `params int[]`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var value = Method(1, 2).Select((int[] arr) => new{r = arr[0],c = arr[1]});
        Console.WriteLine(value); //result : { r = 1, c = 2 }
    }

    public static int[] Method(params int[] ints)
    {
        return ints;
    }
}

public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static T Select<T>(this int[] ints,Func<int[],T> func){
        return func(ints);
    }   
}
```

#### new question :

> How would I use in out keywords in this context? Assuming I'm using parameters passed by value from Foo().

you can use `out` keyword :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Method(1, 2).Select( out int r ,out int c);
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
    static int[] Method(int r,int c) => new[] {r,c};
}

public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static void Select(this int[] ints, out int r, out int c) 
    {
        r = ints[0];
        c = ints[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped out great! Thank you. 
Quick question though, in my pseudo-code example the method `Foo(int r, int c)` has two parameters, I'm using these in the Linq query and giving `r = arr[0]` and `c = arr[1]`, why do I have to assign the output of this query into `var value = ...`? Is there a way to do this were I just query and assign `r` and `c` variables and move on to use my newly retrieved values of `r` and `c` in `Foo(int r, int c)`?

Comment: How would I use `in` `out` keywords in this context? Assuming I'm using parameters passed by value from Foo().

Comment: i update the answer for your new question @MatthewJett

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much @IT WeiHan. You really went above and beyond. Wish I could do more to to help your credibility than just upvote your answer.

Comment: It's my pleasure : )